# Using Pylons as a Web Backend

Tags: pylons, backend

I am using Pylons for two things:
1) Serving API requests (returning JSONs describing my SQLAlchemy models)
2) Running a script 24/7 that fetches flight information from the internet (using HTTP) and pushes it into my DB (again using my models).

I am NOT using Pylons as a front end, but as a back end.

What would be the best way for my script to make HTTP request? is urllib / urllib2 my best option here?

How would I run my script constantly and not on a request serving basis? Is Celery / Cronjobs what I am looking for here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question: yes, urllib/urllib2 is probably the best bet.  It has very solid functionality for making HTTP requests to someone else.

Regarding your second question: Use your database. It's not super-scalable, but it's easy to implement a system where you have a flag in the database that is, essentially, an on-off switch for the application. Once that exists, make a page (with whatever security precautions you think prudent) that sets the flag and starts the application on a loop that continues indefinitely as long as the flag is set. A second page clears the flag, should you need to stop the HTTP requests without killing the entire server process. Instead of 'pages,' they could also be shell scripts or short standalone scripts.  The important part is that you can implement this without requiring Celery or cron (although if you're already familiar with either, have at).